# why DSolve in V 12 returned an internal module variables with $ on them in this example?

Tags: differential-equations, scoping

Fyi, Reported to WRI in case it is a bug. [**CASE:4288939**]

---

Is this supposed to happen?

```
ClearAll[y, x, a]; 
DSolve[(1+(y'[x])^2)(ArcTan[y'[x]]+a x)+y'[x]==0,y[x],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the `$` on the variable `K`. I do not think I've seen this before, but may be I did and forgot.

Why it happens and is this considered a defect?

Btw, in  V 11.3, this does not happen because the ODE is not solved

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So this seems to be something new in V12.

V 12 on windows 10.

Comment: "New Features" (guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn120) mentions "improved nonlinear first-order equation solving."  I'm not sure why you get a `Module` version of `K` instead of `K[1]`, though.

Comment: You may know this, and it's not central to the question, but the solution of a Lagrange equation in the form $x=f(y′)$ can be given in terms of $K = y'$: $x = f(y'), y = \int y' \,dx = \int y'\,f'(y') \, d(y')$, which is equivalent to the algebraic system returned by `DSolve`. (Sorry, wanted to fix the typo in my earlier comment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[y, x, a];
```

From the documentation for [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html): "DSolve can give implicit solutions in terms of Solve."

```
sol = DSolve[(1 + (y'[x])^2) (ArcTan[y'[x]] + a x) + y'[x] == 0, y[x], x]

(* Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

Solve[{y[x] == 1/(a (1 + K$8730^2)) + C[1], 
  x == (-K$8730 - ArcTan[K$8730] - K$8730^2 ArcTan[K$8730])/(
   a (1 + K$8730^2))}, {y[x], K$8730}] *)
```

Setting the arbitrary constant to zero.

```
{x, y} = (sol[[1]] /. C[1] -> 0)[[All, 2]] // Reverse

(* {(-K$8730 - ArcTan[K$8730] - K$8730^2 ArcTan[K$8730])/(a (1 + K$8730^2)), 1/(
 a (1 + K$8730^2))} *)

vars = Variables[Level[x, {-1}]]

(* {a, K$8730} *)

ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {a, -10, 10}, Evaluate@{vars[[2]], -1, 1},
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, ColorData["Rainbow"][v]]]
```

[image]